# Сбор данных температуры с локальных ПК

Tags: парсер

Дано: 80 ПК в разных городах связанных через ВПН.
В каждый ПК подключен датчик температуры, который выгружает показания на этот ПК в файл *.dat
вида:

```
[25.05.2018 17:32:42]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:44]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:46]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:48]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:50]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250
```

и так далее с заданным интервалом. В данном случае интервал 2 секунды.
Как реализовать выгрузку последнего показания температуры со всех ПК в один файл?
Датчик Rodos-5, обслуживающее его ПО - BM1707.

Comment: >>Как можно собрать все показания со всех ПК<< Последовательного с каждого компа по сети. Потом слить всё в один файл. Вот и будет вам со всех ПК в одном файле.

Comment: Нужен автоматический сбор. Как это реализовать?

Comment: эм... вам уже ответили. По сети. Пишите клиента и сборщика. Пускай клиент передаёт сборщику данные по запросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов масса. Зависит от возможностей. Навскидку, например так:

1. Каждый комп обязываете файл с показаниями, скидывать куда-то на сервер (какой-то) под определённым именем (PC-1.measure.html...). Как обязать? Вариантов масса, самый простой - через какой-нить планировщик и ftp на сервере.
2. Далее, на сервере, любыми средствами набор этих показаний(PC-1..PC-2..) сливаете в один файл. Тут уже зависит от входного и выходного формата, чтобы понять как.

В принципе, вопрос можно решить исполняемыми скриптами системы, можно заморочиться, и что то более серьёзное написать. Тут зависит от платформ, чтобы понять, какой инструмент для этого будет лучше использовать.

Comment: ну, тогда сразу можно скачать облачный синхронизатор, либо p2p синхронизатор, связать в кучу все 80 машин (чтобы они все шарили одну и ту же папку друг другу), и каждому дать задание на сбор данных в файлик с именем текущего ПК в папку синхронизации. Или создавать 80 папок, и тогда не будте проблем с отловом изменений у синхронизатора. Хотя, тут уже нужен будет интернет)