# Сбор данных из нескольких файлов .dat в один любого формата

Tags: парсер

Дано: 80 ПК в разных городах связанных через ВПН. В каждый ПК подключен датчик температуры, который выгружает показания на этот ПК в файл *.dat вида:

```
[25.05.2018 17:32:42]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:44]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:46]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:48]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250 
[25.05.2018 17:32:50]> B90416A18B28FF28=22,6250
```

и так далее с заданным интервалом. В данном случае интервал 2 секунды. Как реализовать выгрузку последнего показания температуры со всех ПК в один файл? Датчик Rodos-5, обслуживающее его ПО - BM1707.

Comment: `B90416A18B28FF28` - это идентификатор датчика? если так загнать всё это в одну БД (если надо), или просто обрабатывать по мере поступления, выделяя нужное и сбрасывая в предназначенный для этого файл.

Comment: *последнего показания температуры* Интересно, какой смысл в селективной выгрузке данных, которые устарели через 2 секунды после их создания...

Comment: Интересует мониторинг температуры со всех ПК. Открываешь файл и видишь последние показания со всех. Сейчас нужно открывать каждый по отдельности. Да, это идентификатор датчика.

Comment: Ну в чём сложности? пишите свой сборщик/парсер. Или Вы надеетесь найти готовый?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сбор данных температуры с локальных ПК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833169/%d0%a1%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%9f%d0%9a)